# Combat Expertise/Readied Action

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

If one readies an attack using the combat expertise feat, does one immediately get the dodge bonus to AC, or only until after the attack is actually initiated?

Answer (score 6):

Only when the attack actually follows through. It triggers on you using the attack action or full-attack action, not for any other action, including initiative actions like readying.